# Does the word 'melao' have any special meaning when it is used as a name?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, names

Yesterday, I told an Indian my English name is 'Melao', he smiled and asked me if there's any special meaning. In fact, I get this name from a song with Latin style -- 'Corazon De Melao', I think it's legibly.

So, I wonder if there's any special meaning in English-speaking countries when it is used as a name? Or what's your feeling when you hear a boy with a name 'melao'?

Thx in advance.

Comment: It doesn't have a meaning in English. Maybe it has a meaning in another language that the person speaks.

Answer (score 4):

*Melao* is not an English word. *Corazon de melao* is Latin American Spanish, and literally means “heart of honey”.

*Melado* is an adjective meaning “honey-coloured”, “sweet”, “treacly”; [apparently](https://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100404181231AAk7FBC) in Colombia and Venezuela it’s common to omit the *d*. The French word for *honey* is similar, *miel;* a cognate in English can be found in *mellifluous;* and [*molasses*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/molasses?q=molasses) is derived from the equivalent Portuguese word. The ultimate root is the Latin *mel,* “honey”.

An English equivalent to *corazon de melao* might be *sweetheart*.

> **sweet•heart** *noun*
>   **1.** A person with whom someone is having a romantic or sexual relationship:
>        *the pair were childhood sweethearts*
>        **1.1** Used as a term of endearment or affectionate form of address:
>             *don’t worry, sweetheart, I’ve got it all worked out*
>         **1.2** A particularly lovable or pleasing person or thing:
>             *he is an absolute sweetheart*
>
> [[ODO]](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sweetheart?q=sweetheart)

Comment: The Spanish word for honey is also *miel*.  Lax speech everywhere skips the *d* in *-ado* words, but it is not “well-spoken”, and I’m surprised to see it written. You forgot the most obvious honey word: *melon*, which is *melón* in Spanish and *melão* in Portuguese. In fact, I thought that’s what this really was, but then it would have been *Coração de melão*.

Comment: @tchrist I got the impression from what I read that Latin American Spanish is diverging from Castilian Spanish, and *-ao* for *-ado* is becoming Standard.

Comment: Show it to me in a newspaper, and I’ll believe it.  Otherwise it looks like eye-dialect to me.

Comment: "Meli" μέλι is also Greek for honey.  The name Melissa comes from Greek; it means honeybee. Caramel, in some languages a generic word for candy, comes from Greek "Kara" (dark) and Meli, honey. When honey is boiled to remove most of the liquid, the result is caramel.

Answer (score 2):

I am from the Dominican Republic, at one point the biggest export of sugar cane in the world and responsible for supplying 90% of the world's sugar. The two main sugar refineries were located; one in San Pedro De Macoris and the second in Rio  Haina ( my hometown ) and no one knows more about the sugar production than the Haina kids because all of our great grandparents worked and ran the refineries for decades leaving the jobs to our grand parents then our parents.

This translation about Melao is very much wrong.

"Melao" actually happens to be a concentrated extract from sugarcane. It's very dark in color and sweeter than anything you've ever tasted, so much that you can't hardly consume it by itself but you can use it the same way sugar or honey is used. Some of my countryman squeeze lime or orange and drink it as a homemade energy drink because of the pure sugar wil give you a rush like no other.

Answer (score -1):

I think your friend may have bewrayed his cultural inclination towards the sound of names.  I would not call his reaction prejudicial (because of the negative connotation) but even hearing one's own name in a foreign language, or its phonal interpretation can be unintentionally humorous.

I have a name that is homophonic in nature, and this has led to many 'smiling' explanations that mine did not have that "special meaning".